# .htaccess mod_rewrite causes 500 instead of 404 (infinite internal redirects)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My target is to remove .php extensions from URLs and create Semantic URL multilingual site. Here is my .htaccess rules:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
    
#Remove .php extensions from files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
    
#Create Semantic url
RewriteRule  ^event/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$  calendar?region=$1&news_id=$2 [L,NC]
    
#Handle language switch.
RewriteRule ^(ru)/(.*)$  $2?sitelang=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(ru)$  $1?sitelang=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/(.*)$  $2?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)$  $1?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
    
#404 Document /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

So I have some cases when this rules work but also when does not work. So here are the working ones:

- domain.com/**ru**/event/region/some-event-name
- domain.com/event/region/some-event-name

And the ones which do not work(when I add something, bold), causes 500 error:

- domain.com/event**s**/region/some-event-name
- domain.com/event**s**/region/some-event-name/
- domain.com/event/region/some-event-name/**something**

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop rule execution for existing files and directories. Have your rules as this:

```
#404 Document /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Remove .php extensions from files
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

#Create Semantic url
RewriteRule ^event/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ calendar?region=$1&news_id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#Handle language switch.
RewriteRule ^(ru)/(.*)$  $2?sitelang=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(ru)$  $1?sitelang=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/(.*)$  $2?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)$  $1?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @anubhava for pointing me to right direction. I was able to solve my problem with your help. Here is the working solution.

```
#404 Document /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

#Remove .php extensions from files
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Create Semantic url
RewriteRule ^event/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ calendar?region=$1&news_id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#Handle language switch.
RewriteRule ^(ru)/(.*)$  $2?sitelang=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en)/(.*)$  $2?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?sitelang=1 [L,QSA]
```